# Contacts app not showing in Applications

Tags: slingshot, appcenter

I installed the "Contacts" app in the AppCenter and it does not appear in the Applications list ([slingshot](/questions/tagged/slingshot)).  How do I run it?

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal and paste

> **sudo nano /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Contacts.desktop**

Look for

> **OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity**

and add Pantheon after Unity

> **OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;Pantheon;**

Then click **ctrl+x** and then **y** and **Enter** to save it.

Now search for contacts in **Slingshot**.

Answer (score 1):

There are two contacts apps currently in AppCenter, but if you mean the one with the brown icon, just run:

#### `gnome-contacts`

(Full path is `/usr/bin/gnome-contacts`.) The easiest way to add a Applications menu (called Slingshot) item is likely [MenuLibre](https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/).